# Error Message With Dowloading DLIB On Windows 10

Tags: python, error-handling, dlib

I am trying to download dlib and i am using this code

`pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f`

whenever I run it, I get this error message

`dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

How do I fix this? I am using dlib for a facial recognition software

Comment: to download use `pip download` instead of `pip install`

Comment: do you use 64-bit Python 3.6 ?

Comment: I fixed it, thank you!